# SharePoint equivalent of Session_End in Global.asax

Tags: session, aspnet-lifecycle

**Is there a SharePoint equivalent of the `Session_End` method, like the one in a normal ASP.NET Web Application Project?**

I want to run some code when a user's Session ends, just like you would in a normal ASP.NET Web Application. The code takes data collected during the Session and stores it away.

I've read [an article that describes how to enable Session State in SharePoint 2010 Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/markarend/using-session-state-in-sharepoint-2010), but I'm not sure what this actually means in my case.

I've also read [an article about adding a HTTP Module that inspects Sessions an acts upon them](https://web.archive.org/web/20110410003837/http://theviewfromlevel9.wordpress.com:80/2010/04/20/how-to-use-an-httpmodule-to-handle-a-redirect-on-session_end/), but I'm not sure how this would work in SharePoint.

Comment: is the information critical to your application, do you still receive those events if the app pool dies/server restarts?

Comment: @djeeg Not critical. It's the same type of information I'd want from `Session_End`.

Answer (score 2):

A similar post already answered this:

[SharePoint equivalent of Application Start in Global.asax](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11054/sharepoint-equivalent-of-application-start-in-global-asax)

SharePoint implements its own compiled assembly to handle events in the Global.asax and the class is sealed so you can't inherit it and override. You need to write a custom HTTP module to tap into the ASP.NET pipeline.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://theviewfromlevel9.wordpress.com/2010/04/20/how-to-use-an-httpmodule-to-handle-a-redirect-on-session_end/ Are you sure this will work with SharePoint? Sessions seem a bit quirky in SharePoint.